# How do I view questions by week/month in the app?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

This is my most-used feature on Stack Exchange. I don't visit most SE sites regularly so it's great to come to a site I haven't visited for a while and see what are the best questions from the past week or month.

However I don't see any way to do that with the mobile app (iPhone), an I missing something?

Comment: "am I missing something" > Yes, this feature being implemented. Can you give a link to what you currently use on the main site?

Comment: I use the "month" option from the dropdown, eg http://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=month